# Proper NSCalendar initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

Our app works quite a bit with dates, but at this time we only support the Gregorian calendar and an app wide NSCalendar instance is initialized as follows:

```
NSCalendar *appCalendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

The docs of the above method states that "The returned calendar defaults to the current locale and default time zone." However, when running the app on a device with the region set to "United Kingdom", calling `[appCalendar firstWeekday]` returned a value of 1 (Sunday) rather than the expected 2 (Monday). If I run `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]`, the correct value of 2 is returned. At first I thought that a locale may not be set on "appCalendar", but logging revealed it had one, though it lacked a countrycode etc., which the "currentCalendar" instance does have and which allows it to return the correct firstWeekDay.

Should a locale explicitly be set on the object returned from `calendarWithIdentifier` and if so, are there any considerations in doing so?

**Update**

Based on zrzka's answer below, I recommend that a locale is explicitly set when initializing a calendar with an identifier e.g.

```
NSCalendar *appCalendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

appCalendar.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1412400-calendarwithidentifier?language=objc) is wrong:

> The returned calendar defaults to the current locale and default time zone.

It should be:

> The returned calendar defaults to the system locale and default time zone.

[`CFCalendar.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFCalendar.c.auto.html):

```c
CFCalendarRef CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFStringRef identifier) {
    if (allocator == NULL) allocator = __CFGetDefaultAllocator();
    __CFGenericValidateType(allocator, CFAllocatorGetTypeID());
    __CFGenericValidateType(identifier, CFStringGetTypeID());
    // return NULL until Chinese calendar is available
    if (identifier != kCFGregorianCalendar && identifier != kCFBuddhistCalendar && identifier != kCFJapaneseCalendar && identifier != kCFIslamicCalendar && identifier != kCFIslamicCivilCalendar && identifier != kCFHebrewCalendar) {
//    if (identifier != kCFGregorianCalendar && identifier != kCFBuddhistCalendar && identifier != kCFJapaneseCalendar && identifier != kCFIslamicCalendar && identifier != kCFIslamicCivilCalendar && identifier != kCFHebrewCalendar && identifier != kCFChineseCalendar) {
    if (CFEqual(kCFGregorianCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFGregorianCalendar;
    else if (CFEqual(kCFBuddhistCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFBuddhistCalendar;
    else if (CFEqual(kCFJapaneseCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFJapaneseCalendar;
    else if (CFEqual(kCFIslamicCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFIslamicCalendar;
    else if (CFEqual(kCFIslamicCivilCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFIslamicCivilCalendar;
    else if (CFEqual(kCFHebrewCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFHebrewCalendar;
//  else if (CFEqual(kCFChineseCalendar, identifier)) identifier = kCFChineseCalendar;
    else return NULL;
    }
    struct __CFCalendar *calendar = NULL;
    uint32_t size = sizeof(struct __CFCalendar) - sizeof(CFRuntimeBase);
    calendar = (struct __CFCalendar *)_CFRuntimeCreateInstance(allocator, CFCalendarGetTypeID(), size, NULL);
    if (NULL == calendar) {
    return NULL;
    }
    calendar->_identifier = (CFStringRef)CFRetain(identifier);
    calendar->_locale = NULL;
    calendar->_localeID = CFLocaleGetIdentifier(CFLocaleGetSystem());
    calendar->_tz = CFTimeZoneCopyDefault();
    calendar->_cal = NULL;
    return (CFCalendarRef)calendar;
}
```

`_locale` is initialized with `NULL` and `_localeID` is initialized with locale identifier of the system locale (which is an empty string on iPhone & simulator). `_cal` is set to `NULL`.

```c
CFIndex CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday(CFCalendarRef calendar) {
    CF_OBJC_FUNCDISPATCHV(CFCalendarGetTypeID(), CFIndex, calendar, firstWeekday);
    __CFGenericValidateType(calendar, CFCalendarGetTypeID());
    if (!calendar->_cal) __CFCalendarSetupCal(calendar);
    if (calendar->_cal) {
    return ucal_getAttribute(calendar->_cal, UCAL_FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So, because `_cal` is `NULL`, `__CFCalendarSetupCal` is called.

```c
static void __CFCalendarSetupCal(CFCalendarRef calendar) {
    calendar->_cal = __CFCalendarCreateUCalendar(calendar->_identifier, calendar->_localeID, calendar->_tz);
}
```

Which calls `__CFCalendarCreateUCalendar` with `_localeID` which is an empty string.

I can confirm this behavior on iOS 11, 12 & 13. The source code is for something called *CF-Lite*, but I went further and disassembled actual CoreFoundation framework and it does the same thing ...

```
call       _CFLocaleGetSystem             ; _CFLocaleGetSystem
mov        rdi, rax                       ; argument "cf" for method _CFRetain
call       _CFRetain                      ; _CFRetain
mov        qword [r15+0x18], rax
call       _CFTimeZoneCopyDefault         ; _CFTimeZoneCopyDefault
mov        qword [r15+0x20], rax
mov        rbx, qword [r15+0x10]
mov        rdi, qword [r15+0x18]          ; argument "locale" for method _CFLocaleGetIdentifier
call       _CFLocaleGetIdentifier         ; _CFLocaleGetIdentifier
mov        rdx, qword [r15+0x20]          ; argument #3 for method ___CFCalendarCreateUCalendar
mov        rdi, rbx                       ; argument #1 for method ___CFCalendarCreateUCalendar
mov        rsi, rax                       ; argument #2 for method ___CFCalendarCreateUCalendar
call       ___CFCalendarCreateUCalendar   ; ___CFCalendarCreateUCalendar
```

... using an empty identifier from `CFLocaleGetIdentifier` from `CFLocaleGetSystem`.

When you check the [`CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1533511-cfcalendarcreatewithidentifier?language=objc) documentation, there's not a word about current locale, time zone, ...

What's even more interesting is the difference (section Discussion) for these two methods:

- [`+calendarWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1412400-calendarwithidentifier?language=objc)

  - It contains the info about current locale, ...
- [`-initWithCalendarIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1415991-initwithcalendaridentifier?language=objc)

  - Not a word about current locale, ...

But there's no difference, `calendarWithIdentifier:` just calls the `alloc` & `initWithCalendarIdentifier:`.

```
push       rbp
mov        rbp, rsp
push       r14
push       rbx
mov        rbx, rdx
mov        rsi, qword [0x3cb478]                       ; argument "selector" for method _objc_msgSend, @selector(alloc)
mov        r14, qword [_objc_msgSend_390220]           ; _objc_msgSend_390220
call       r14                                         ; Jumps to 0x553ae0 (_objc_msgSend), _objc_msgSend
mov        rsi, qword [0x3cc768]                       ; argument "selector" for method _objc_msgSend, @selector(initWithCalendarIdentifier:)
...
```

I believe it's a documentation problem which should be reported to Apple (did it, [FB7740798](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7740798)).